# How to add properties files in multi module spring maven project to class path?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, properties

I have a multi module maven spring boot project with 2 services (executable jars) and 3 libraries (only loaded as dependencies).

Project Structure is

```
|--- Parent Project
|      |--- pom.xml
|      |--- libraries
|      |    | --- lib1
|      |    |    |--- some code
|      |    |    |--- pom.xml
|      |    |--- lib2
|      |    |    |--- some code
|      |    |    |--- pom.xml
|      |--- services
|      |    | --- service1
|      |    |    |--- src
|      |    |    |     |--- main
|      |    |    |     |--- ressources
|      |    |    |     |    |--- several .properties files
|      |    |    |--- pom.xml
|      |    | --- service2
|      |    |    |--- src
|      |    |    |     |--- main
|      |    |    |     |--- ressources
|      |    |    |     |    |--- several .properties files
|      |    |    |--- pom.xml
```

my dependencies are working well and I can use the modules altogether, configured as follows in parent pom

```
<groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>

<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>libraries/lib1</module>
    <module>libraries/lib2</module>
    <module>services/service1</module>
    <module>services/service2</module>
</modules>
...
```

But I have a problem with the build process. This in configured as this in the parent pom

```
 <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

At the moment I only want to build service1. The build process also works. In the pom of service1 it is configured as follows:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>${target.directory}</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.soemstuff.mainclass</mainClass>
                <outputDirectory>${target.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <finalName>service1-${revision}</finalName>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <outputDirectory>${target.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>Dockerfile</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As said before, I create an executable jar into the target/service1 directory at the root of my project. But spring fails on startup because it says, the spring.properties (I defined several config files, non can be found) does not exists. Bit if I start the project from IntelliJ it works (I defined the properties files with annotations).

Funfact, when I delete all target directories and use "mvn package" in the root pom, maven generates also the target of the submodules (service1). Now it does not find the properties files either, when I start it in IntelliJ. When I delete the target folder of service1 afterwards and start it from IntelliJ it works.

Can anyone help me packaging the properties into the jar? It would be also an option to copy the files in the same directory as the .jar but I tried and spring can not find it because its obviously not in the class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that the maven resources plugin in my service1.pom, which I used to copy the Dockerfile to my custom target directory in the root was the problem. I deleted the plugin and now the build works as expected.

Thats oke but I could not find out why. If anyone knows a reason for that, feel free to write a comment.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
            <outputDirectory>${target.directory}</outputDirectory>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                    <includes>
                        <include>Dockerfile</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```